# Things to keep in mind while developing iPad Application from existing iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, ipad

I would like to know some of the things before entering into the arena of iPad.

I have iPhone Application in AppStore. Now going to start the work on same app for iPad, so what are the things that I should keep in mind before developing it ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First advice, if you don't have an iPad (like in Europe most of us :(), build yourself a paper model. Helps, trust me :)

When talking about usability and UI then I recomment you read the 99 page iPad usability analysis document. http://www.useit.com/alertbox/ipad.html (link to the PDF on the bottom of the page).

Comment: Additionally, Apple has a document on usability for migratingfrom iPhone to iPad http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/general/conceptual/ipadhig/Strategies/Strategies.html. Also, the Smoking Apples article "The Good, the Bad, and Ugly, of iPad app user interfaces" is a good luck at good and bad migrations http://smokingapples.com/opinion/ipad-ui/.

Answer (score 1):

Providing your app has been well designed, the biggest thing is obviously going to be your UI. Where as the iPhone is more likely to have multiple pages/tabs, iPad apps generally seem to work best when everything is accessible from one page. Take advantage of that screen-size, and in particular take advantage of popovers. For example, if your application uses a UITabBarController and has 3 tabs, consider making the first tab your main page of your iPad app, and the other 2 tabs accessible via UIPopovers. Spend some time designing your UI before jumping into the code and you'll be fine.

A secondary thing to consider is whether you want a universal app, or two separate applications. You may like to reward users who already own the iPhone version by creating a universal app (as they will get it for free), but then they may also expect their data to be synched between the iPhone & iPad. Generally, it's my opinion that apps should be universal, as this has other advantages. If you app is universal, then any reviews/sales will affect your positions/rating in both the iPhone and the iPad app store, where as if you have two apps they are completely separate.

Something else to consider is what your Base SDK is currently set to. Apps which support iPhone OS 2.X can't be upgraded to iPad apps, so if your app is currently supporting 2.X you will possibly cut out some users with an upgrade.

Other than that, you might want to consider making a simple test iPad app first up, just to get a feel for the new controls. You'll then have a much better idea of how they can be effectively used in your app.

Answer (score -3):

You should use color pallette when you are designing.

You should look many applications which are similar with yours.

You should announce your application before to finish it.

You should prepare a good user interface. Everything must be under my hands.

And you should aim to make unbelieveable things.